# iOS 8 Extension for selected text

Tags: ios8, ios-app-extension

In iOS 8 we can now create extensions which match up with "extension points" in other apps of a few kinds: "Today" extensions that appear as views on the Lock & notifications screens, "share" extensions that can open data and files from other apps, etc. Is it possible to create an extension which will take selected text from another app, and if so how is it done?

Comment: iOS 8 is still under NDA, you should be posting this in the Apple Dev Forums :)

Comment: Yes. I like to know it too. Did you found any posts?

Comment: FYI: There is no Apple NDA this year; everyone has been posting blogs and asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can access selected text from your container app, or from apps within the same access group, but not from other third party apps.